# How can I use Itext7 in unity C#

Tags: unity-game-engine, pdf, uwp, itext7

I'm a beginner in unity. I got itext7donet .dll from github and moved all .dll into Unity project's Assets/Plugins folder.But the console told me "Unable to resolve reference 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions'. Is the assembly missing or incompatible with the current platform?"

Next,I got Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll and moved it to Unity project's Assets/Plugins.But the console told me "Unable to resolve reference 'System.memory','System.Runtime.loader',etc". This makes me realize that I was wrong. I'm looking forward to getting a proper way to configure itext7 in unity.
Thank you so much!